# Add chroma noise to image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I'm training a deep neural network to improve the quality of images. The images contain some specific types of noise that I want to reduce/remove by means of a deep learning model. In order to do so I'm using a huge dataset of similar clear high-res images with barely any noise, add the specific types of noise to the images and train the network on regenerating the original image (a custom autoencoder network). With one of the several noise types this works very well so far. Without going to far into the details, adding that particular type of noise was easy.

Now I need to add another noise type to the images, more precisely: chroma noise like in the following image (the bottom right one): [link](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/_B9QptPHH85Y/R_IyDJqWyMI/AAAAAAAAEuM/szptcB5PImg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/Chroma+Noise.jpg)

How do I artificially generate and add chroma noise to an image in Python? I can use the full range of image processing packages, PIL, numpy, OpenCV, torchvision...

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert the image to a colorspace such as [HSV](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) or [CIE Lab](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space). You then add noise to the chromacity channels (a, b in Lab, or H, S is HSV). Finally, convert back to RGB.

This colorspace conversion step is very common and most image toolkits should have that functionality.

Comment: Okay, I can add random, pixelbased chroma noise by that. But the noise that I'd like to add (rather remove) is on a superpixel level (as seen in the linked image). The blotches are rather big compared to a single pixel. I suppose that's some perlin or fractal noise but I've so far been unable to replicate it like that. It somehow looks like chroma noise that comes from a high ISO camera.

Comment: @HendrikWiese: I think that is caused by JPEG compression. I can see JPEG compression artifacts also in the luminance noise component. JPEG downsamples the chromacity components of the image, which leads to blotches like that if you isolate them. I would try to save as JPEG and then load back in. Or you could try to simulate that by bluring the noise before you add it to the chromacity components of the image.

Comment: Okay, yeah, JPEG artifacts, rather their removal, are a thing that I want to incorporate into the model as well, thanks. I'll see if it helps.